# Exponential distribution and independent random variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

**The waiting time T (in hours) between each call Tom receives is random with the density function
$f(t)=1.4e^{-1.4t}$ for $t\geq0$
For two independent waiting times $T_1$ and $T_2$, find the probability that both $T_1$ and $T_2$ are greater than 1.**

So I have to find $P(T_1>1, T_2>1)=P(T_1>1)*P(T_2>1)$. Is it right that $P(T_1>1)=P(T_2>1)$ when I am calculating this, or am I wrong?

Comment: $T_1$ and $T_2$ have the same distribution (and are independent).  So $P(T_1>1)=P(T_2>1)$.  Note the question says "greater than 1" not "greater than 0".

Comment: Of course, my bad. I will edit the the post. But thank you for the confirmation :)

Comment: In R, `pexp` is an exponential CDF. The second argument is the rate. Code `(1 - pexp(1, 1.4))^2` returns $0.06081006.$